# change div html content after Ajax done function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've got the following div:

```
<div class="progress" id="progress-bar"></div>
```

The following javascript with the ajax call does return 0 as data. It doesn't however add the html content to the div when I put the code in the .done part of the ajax call. When i put that code at the start of the javascript the progress bar appears with 45% of the bar filled.

```
$("#ipaddress_form").submit(function(e) {           
    var ipjs = $("#input_ipaddress").val();
    var hostjs = $("#input_hostname").val();
    var commjs = $("#input_comms").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "include/handlingJS.inc.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "ipjs": ipjs,
            "hostjs": hostjs,
            "commjs": commjs    
        }

    }).done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
        if(data == 0) {
            bar = $('#progress-bar');
            bar.html('<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%"><span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

Is there something I missed?

Comment: what is the error and is the alert working in .done

Comment: The alert is working fine and returns 0. I have also tried commenting that if function. No result though.

Comment: Parse your response to integer

Comment: $("#progress-bar").length returns 1. So the element does exist inside the .done function. It could be that last thing you mentioned.

Comment: setting the html content directly after submitting the form works. Something must be going on there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the data in the alert box then the error may be

1. the format in which you are getting the response data. It might not be a integer value.
2. It might be a string with white spaces.

you can try `data.trim() == '0'`

Comment: As I said in my other comment I already tried commenting the if function. So it should immediately execute that code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(parseInt(data) === 0) {
        bar = $('#progress-bar');
        bar.html('<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%"><span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span></div>');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied at the part where I was submitting the form. I changed the form submit event to a button click event:

```
$("#loading").on("click", function(e) {
    // do ajax stuff here
}
```

I can't however explain why it works, though.